# Pandas: Add column name to third column for multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have multiple csv files in same directory. Each csv file contains 3 columns but in 3rd column, column name is missing. To read all csv files I had to use `error_bad_lines=False`. Now, I want to add column name `c3` to third column for multiple csv files.

Sample df:

```
v     info  
12    days    6
53    x       a
42    y       b
```

Expected output:

```
    v    info   c3
0  12    days    6
1  53    x       a
2  42    y       b
```

Comment: After reading the file, you can use: `df.columns=['v', 'info', 'c3']`

Comment: But how do I loop through for multiple csv files?

Comment: `for file in os.listdir(your_dir):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your csv looks like, so I assumed that your csv would be:

```
v,info,
12,days,6
53,x,a
42,y,b
```

Whatever, you can load all the csv file in a directory and change column names as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

for f in glob.glob("C:\*.csv"):
    print(f)  # f is a file name
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.reset_index() # add index column, 0, 1, 2, ...
    df.columns = ['v', 'info', 'c3'] # change column names
    df.to_csv(f)  # save it (overwriting)
```

You can see how to use `glob` to load files in a directory in detail here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

First, convert index "v" into column

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Then, you can change the columns simply.

```
df.columns = ["v", "info", "c3"]
```

Finally,

```
import pandas as pd
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df = df.reset_index() # this is option line
        df.columns = ["v", "info", "c3"]
        df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: But how do I loop through for multiple csv files in same directory?

Comment: Do you need to merge them while looping through multiple csv files in same dir?

Comment: Not merge actually. Just add column name for all csv files.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'v': [12,53,42], 'info':['days','x','y'], '':[6,'a','b']})
cols = list(a.columns)[:2]
cols.append('col3')
a.columns = cols
a
```

output:

[image]

or, simply:

```
a.rename(columns={'':'new'})
```